# In AOSP which class sends SCREEN_OFF / ON broadcast

Tags: android, android-source, broadcast

I am having trouble identifying the code that sends the SCREEN_ON / SCREEN_OFF broadcast. In specific I am looking in Android 5.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SCREEN_ON`/`SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts are send from [`services/core/java/com/android/server/power/Notifier.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r3/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/Notifier.java).

Creation of the `SCREEN_ON` intent ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r3/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/Notifier.java#124)):

```
        mScreenOnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
```

Sending of the broadcast ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r3/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/Notifier.java#444)):

```
            mContext.sendOrderedBroadcastAsUser(mScreenOnIntent, UserHandle.ALL, null,
                    mWakeUpBroadcastDone, mHandler, 0, null, null);
```

Analogously for `SCREEN_OFF`.

The `Notifier` is turn controlled by the `PowerManagerService` ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r3/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java#501)).